# variable textview not working

Tags: android, variables, textview

i have this code and i cant get the variable string from here

```
private void location() {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.alquila, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) promptView.findViewById(R.id.gen);
    Random r = new Random();
    int i = r.nextInt(101);
    tv.setText(i +"");
    final String passwd = tv.getText().toString();
    final AlertDialog alertD = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

    Button btnAdd1 = (Button) promptView.findViewById(R.id.button3);


    btnAdd1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new SendPostRequest().execute();
            Toast.makeText(login.this, passwd, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // btnAdd1 has been clicked
            alertD.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alertD.setView(promptView);

    alertD.show();
}
```

And i need get the variable string "passwd" to...

```
public class SendPostRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute(){}

    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        try {

            URL url = new URL("https://www.domain.org/file.php"); // here is

            JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();
            postDataParams.put("mensajeArea", passwd);
            Log.e("params",postDataParams.toString());

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();

            int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new
                        InputStreamReader(
                        conn.getInputStream()));

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String line="";

                while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                    sb.append(line);
                    break;
                }

                in.close();
                return sb.toString();

            }
            else {
                return new String("false : "+responseCode);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

here --> postDataParams.put("mensajeArea", **passwd**);

help, I've been trying for hours without success...

Comment: You can't do it. Because SendPostRequest doesn't know anything about local variable in location method

Comment: How could I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that

```
public class SendPostRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private String passwd;
    public SendPostRequest(String pass) {
        super();
        this.passwd = pass;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        try {

            URL url = new URL("https://www.domain.org/file.php"); // here is

            JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();
            postDataParams.put("mensajeArea", passwd);
            Log.e("params", postDataParams.toString());

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
                        InputStreamReader(
                        conn.getInputStream()));

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String line = "";

                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                    sb.append(line);
                    break;
                }

                in.close();
                return sb.toString();

            } else {
                return new String("false : " + responseCode);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Create task with the help of constructor and set passwd

In onclick:

```
btnAdd1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new SendPostRequest(passwd).execute();
        Toast.makeText(login.this, passwd, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // btnAdd1 has been clicked
        alertD.dismiss();
    }
});
```